Angular SSR ngIf rendered when value is false
I got this weird stuff going on and I can't understand why
                {{!loggedIn}}
                <div class="flex gap-4" *ngIf="!loggedIn">
                    <button
                        [routerLink]="['/auth', 'register']"
                        class="cursor-pointer rounded bg-primary-100 px-4 py-2 text-primary-400 hover:bg-primary-50"
                    >
                        Get Started
                    </button>
                    <button
                        [routerLink]="['/auth', 'login']"
                        class="cursor-pointer rounded bg-primary-100 px-4 py-2 text-primary-400 hover:bg-primary-50"
                    >
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>

Then I have
   ngOnInit () {
    this.loggedIn = false
    this.authStateService.subscribe(val=> {
        this.loggedIn = val.isAuthenticated;
    })
}

the result looks like this:

This is the bootstrap:
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ApplicationConfig, mergeApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core'
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { appConfig } from './app.config'

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideServerRendering(),
        provideClientHydration(),
        provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    ],
}

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig)

Question is: why is it rendered, when it shouldn't be?

Check your console, you likely have a hydration issue.

There's nothing in the console @MatthieuRiegler :/

You can also use this.loggedIn$ = this.authStateService then use async pipe on the ngIf like <div class="flex gap-4" *ngIf="!(loggedIn$ | async)">
Another problem might be ngIf is true on the server, but false on the browser, to make html render only on the browser you can use @defer block
       @defer() {
            <div class="flex gap-4" *ngIf="!loggedIn">
                <button
                    [routerLink]="['/auth', 'register']"
                    class="cursor-pointer rounded bg-primary-100 px-4 py-2 text-primary-400 hover:bg-primary-50"
                >
                    Get Started
                </button>
                <button
                    [routerLink]="['/auth', 'login']"
                    class="cursor-pointer rounded bg-primary-100 px-4 py-2 text-primary-400 hover:bg-primary-50"
                >
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
       }

Maybe your component is having change detection as OnPush so trigger a manual change detection, after the subscribe callback.
...
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
...

...
ngOnInit () {
    this.loggedIn = false
    this.authStateService.subscribe(val=> {
        this.loggedIn = val.isAuthenticated;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    })
}


What if i do want to render it on the server?

I also did try the detectChanges() manually, but nothing happens, as if this region is not under the control of angular. supper weird.
I think you might be onto something. The initial state is loggedIn =false. then the subject changes, and loggedIn becomes true. However, the two way data binding is not working. :/

@Stefa did you try defer method. Also what do you mean by "the two way data binding is not working"

Yes, @defer() works, but what if I do want to render it on the server? "The two way data binding" i would expect that browser will override the server if the state changes on the frontend.

@Stefa As I explained, window, document, localStorage do not exist on the server, so the content will never be shown (auth is taken from localStorage is my assumption), which is the same as the defer code!

If you are using localStorage on Angular SSR it will not work because localStorage is available only on the client side.
Where are you getting the authentication value from ?

auth is coming from a service that extends the RxJs StateSubject.
